# How to calculate HashMap memory usage in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, hashmap, jvm

I was asked in an interview to calculate the memory usage for `HashMap` and how much estimated memory it will consume if you have 2 million items in it.

For example:

```
Map <String,List<String>> mp=new HashMap <String,List<String>>();
```

The mapping is like this.

```
key   value
----- ---------------------------
abc   ['hello','how']
abz   ['hello','how','are','you']
```

How would I estimate the memory usage of this HashMap Object in Java?

Comment: It depends on what it contains...

Comment: @petar Minchev: it stores value in the map, they wanted me to calculate total memory usage.  This was confusing as it had one key and multiple values.

Comment: @Petar, the hashmap memory allocation is *not* the entire rertained size, it's the overhead of using it (i.e. shallow size)

Comment: huh, now i notice the *multiple* values edition... the question has degraded so badly :(

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/determining_memory_usage_in_java.shtml

Comment: I guess the idea behind the question was not to get an exact answer, but to see how you approach it and lay out the answer? Probably they were looking at something like explaining that Strings in Java are kept in a constant pool, so it is difficult to say without knowing whether there are duplicate strings, and whether those are mapped to one constant or a new object is created, and so on...

Comment: @Yohan, Strings in java are not kept in a constant pool but in the heap.The ones in the constant pool are in the perm-gen and they are literals only (class names are are also literals, for example)

Comment: @bestsss I know that the memory is allocated in the heap. But what happens is, when you say String s = "abc", if "abc" is not in the constant pool, memory is allocated for it and the literal is added to the pool. Next time you say String x = "abc", it refers to the same instance, and no new object is created (thus no memory allocation). But if you say new String("abc") then memory is allocated for the new instance. Therefore, unless you know how those Strings are created, you can't say this much of memory is used. And by the way, PermGen is also part of the heap.

Comment: I would interpret the question ( and ask the interviewer to clarify indicating you understand the ambiguity ) if he means how much memory the hashmap uses to reference the data and keys only as it only storing the handles and keys without the data) vs with the data and keys.  As they are both relevant parts of the same question.  I found this question because I wanted to know if someone had run and posted a set of benchmarks of what a hastable would use in this way given a perfect/typical/optimal/bad distribution in the table ( ie: table utilization )

Comment: Three approaches:  1) Look at the HashMap source, make an "educated" guess what each sub-object occupies (as well as the Strings and arrays), and add together.  2) Use a storage profiling tool.  3) Pull a number out of somewhere.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The short answer**

To find out how large an object is, I would use a profiler. In YourKit, for example, you can search for the object and then get it to calculate its deep size.  This will give a you a fair idea of how much memory would be used if the object were stand alone and is a conservative size for the object.

**The quibbles**

If parts of the object are re-used in other structures e.g. String literals, you won't free this much memory by discarding it. In fact discarding one reference to the HashMap might not free any memory at all.

*What about Serialisation?*

Serialising the object is one approach to getting an estimate, but it can be wildly off as the serialisation overhead and encoding is different in memory and to a byte stream.  How much memory is used depends on the JVM (and whether its using 32/64-bit references), but the Serialisation format is always the same.

e.g.

In Sun/Oracle's JVM, an Integer can take 16 bytes for the header, 4 bytes for the number and 4 bytes padding (the objects are 8-byte aligned in memory), total 24 bytes.  However if you serialise one Integer, it takes 81 bytes, serialise two integers and they takes 91 bytes. i.e. the size of the first Integer is inflated and the second Integer is less than what is used in memory.

String is a much more complex example. In the Sun/Oracle JVM, it contains 3 `int` values and a `char[]` reference.  So you might assume it uses 16 byte header plus 3 * 4 bytes for the `int`s, 4 bytes for the `char[]`, 16 bytes for the overhead of the `char[]` and then two bytes per char, aligned to 8-byte boundary...

*What flags can change the size?*

If you have 64-bit references, the `char[]` reference is 8 bytes long resulting in 4 bytes of padding. If you have a 64-bit JVM, you can use `+XX:+UseCompressedOops` to use 32-bit references. (So look at the JVM bit size alone doesn't tell you the size of its references)

If you have `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings`, the JVM will use a byte[] instead of a char array when it can. This can slow down your application slightly but could improve you memory consumption dramatically.  When a byte[] in used, the memory consumed is 1 byte per char. ;)  Note: for a 4-char String, as in the example, the size used is the same due to the 8-byte boundary.

**What do you mean by "size"?**

As has been pointed out, HashMap and List is more complex as many, if not all, the Strings can be reused, possibly String literals. What you mean by "size" depends on how it is used. i.e. How much memory would the structure use alone? How much would be freed if the structure were discarded? How much memory would be used if you copied the structure? These questions can have different answers.

**What can you do without a profiler?**

If you can determine that the likely conservative size, is small enough, the exact size doesn't matter.  The conservative case is likely to where you construct every String and entry from scratch. (I only say likely as a HashMap can have capacity for 1 billion entries even though it is empty. Strings with a single char can be a sub-string of a String with 2 billion characters)

You can perform a System.gc(), take the free memory, create the objects, perform another System.gc() and see how much the free memory has reduced. You may need to create the object many times and take an average.  Repeat this exercise many times, but it can give you a fair idea.

(BTW While System.gc() is only a hint, the Sun/Oracle JVM will perform a Full GC every time by default)

Comment: besides YourKit which is not free, you can use jmap (+jhat) that are part of JDK.

Comment: YourKit is free on evaluation. I had several before I bought it.  Sometimes in a profession its worth paying for the tools you use.;)

Comment: I can't imagine a carpenter who would only use hammers that he could get for free.

Comment: When you try to get the actual memory using a profiling tool like YourKit, you should know [What Heap Dumps Are Lying To You About](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/)…

Answer (score 6):

I think that the question should be clarified because there is a difference between the size of the HashMap and the size of HashMap + the objects contained by the HashMap.

If you consider the size of the HashMap, in the example you provided, the HashMap stores one reference to the String "aby" and one reference to the List. So the multiple elements in the list do not matter. Only the reference to the list is stored in the value.

In a 32 bits JVM, in one Map entry, you have 4 bytes for the "aby" reference + 4 bytes for the List reference + 4 bytes for the "hashcode" int property of Map entry + 4 bytes for the "next" property of Map entry.

You also add the 4*(X-1) bytes references where the "X" is the number of empty buckets that the HashMap has created when you called the constructor `new HashMap<String,List<String>>()`
. According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html, it should be 16.

There are also loadFactor, modCount, threshold and size which are all primitive int type (16 more bytes) and header (8bytes).

So in the end, the size of your above HashMap would be 4 + 4 + 1 + (4*15) + 16 + 8 = 93 bytes

This is an approximation based on data that are owned by the HashMap. I think that maybe the interviewer was interested in seeing if you were aware of the way HashMap works (the fact for example that the default constructor create and array of 16 buckets for Map entry, the fact that the sizes of the objects stored in the HashMap do not affect the HashMap size since it only store the references).

HashMap are so widely used that under certain circumstances, it should be worth using the constructors with initial capacity and load factor.

Comment: You neglect the memory management overhead of 8 bytes per object, and rounding to 8 bytes of the sizes. A `HashMap.Entry` is 24 Bytes, not 16, for example. For many cases, this adds up to an enormous amount of memory wasted. For example, a `HashMap<Integer, Double>` needs about 100 Bytes per stored value due to boxing, with 12 bytes of actual data, and 88 bytes overhead. Now with Strings, there is no autoboxing, and the strings are not as tiny, so it will not be as massive.

Answer (score 1):

```
Summary:

memory = hashmap_array_size*bucket_size
+ n*chained_list_node_size
+ sum(key string sizes)
+ sum(list_string_size(string_list) for each hashmap List<String> value)

= 254 MB
(theoretical in-interview estimate)

Test program total-memory-used-size for 2 million sample entries: (see below)
= 640 MB
(I recommend a simple test program like this for a quick true-total-size estimate)
```

A minimal estimate (actual implementation probably has a bit more overhead):

Assumed data structure:

```
Bucket: (Pointer to String key, Pointer to hash-chain-list first-node)

Chained List Node: (Pointer to List<String> value, Next-pointer)
(HashMap is a chained hash - each bucket has a list/tree of values)
(as of Java 8, the list switches to a tree after 8 items)

List<String> instance: (Pointer to first node)

List<String> Node: (Pointer to String value, Next-pointer)
```

Assumption to simplify this estimate: zero collisions, each bucket has max 1 value (ask interviewer if this is ok - to give a rough, initial answer)

Assumption: 64-bit JVM so 64-bit pointers so pointer_size=8 bytes

Assumption: HashMap underlying array is 50% full (by default, at 75% full, the hashmap is rehashed with double the size), so hashmap_array_size = 2*n

```
memory = hashmap_array_size*bucket_size
+ n*chained_list_node_size
+ sum(key string sizes)
+ sum(list_string_size(string_list) for each hashmap List<String> value)

So:

memory = (n*2)*(8*2)
+ n*(8*2) + ((2 length_field + 3 string_length)*n)
+ (n*(8 + 3*(8*2)
+ 3*(2 length_field + 4 string_length))
= 2000000*(2*8*2 + 8*2 + (2+3) + (8 + 3*8*2 + 3*(2+4)))
= 254000000
= 254 MB

n = number of items in the hash map

bucket_size = pointer_size*2

chained_list_node_size = pointer_size*2

list_string_size(list) = pointer_size +
list.size()*list_string_node_size
+ sum(string value sizes in this List<String> list)

list_string_node_size = pointer_size*2

String length bytes = length_field_size + string_characters
(UTF-8 is 1 byte per ascii character)
(length_field_size = size of integer = 2)

Assume all keys are length 3.
(we have to assume something to calculate space used)
so: sum(key string sizes) = (2 length_field + 3 string_length)*n

Assume all value string-lists are length 3 and each string is of length 4. So:
sum(list_string_size(string_list) for each hashmap List<String> value)
= n*(8 + 3*(8*2) + 3*(2 length_field + 4 string_length))
```

A simple test program would give a better real answer:

```
import java.util.*;
class TempTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        System.gc();
        printMemory();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i) {
            map.put(String.valueOf(i), Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i) + "b", String.valueOf(i) + "c"));
        }
        System.gc();
        printMemory();
    }

    private static void printMemory() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
        long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();

        System.out.println("Memory: Used=" + (totalMemory - freeMemory) + " Total=" + totalMemory + " Free=" + freeMemory);
    }
}
```

For me, this took 640MB (after.Used - before.Used).

Comment: For my problem, switching from HashMap<Long, Long> to LongLongHashMap (eclipse collections) reduced my memory footprint. From 433MB to 273MB for a sample-test-allocation of 5 million entries (see test program above).

Answer (score 0):

you can't know in advance without knowing what all the strings are, and how many items are in each list, or without knowing if the strings are all unique references.

The only way to know for sure, is to serialize the whole thing to a byte array (or temp file) and see exactly how many bytes that was.

Comment: @john: they asked me for estimated memory usage.  is there any idea how to calculate it?

Comment: they probably asked you the question so that you'd ask all the questions we're asking.  You can't estimate something without enough information, and so far, just a map of lists of strings isn't enough info.  How may items in the map?  average size of each key?  average number of items in each key's list?  average size of each string in each key's list?  etc...

Comment: @John the memory O() of a data structure size the memory the estimated memory per element, a reference of a string in java depends on the architecture and it's between 4 and 8 bytes. What the string, itself. contains is irrelevant to the data structure.

Comment: @bestsss it really depends on if you're arguing the shallow size of the structure itself, or the deep size of the entire structure.  if **I** asked this interview question, i'd be asking it to see what questions the interviewee asked in order to perform the estimate, not for a detailed discussion about the internals of sun/oracle's implementation of HashMap itself.

Comment: @John, but what will you do if you map.put(String.intern(), Boolean.valueOf(b))? I do understand String.intern() might (does) bloat the perm-gen, however you bet you'd get the a similar question on the interview from me.

Comment: @bestsss that would be the kind of comment i'd be looking from the interviewee!

Comment: @John Gardner, The problem with Serialising the data is; Most Serialisation schemes have their own overhead which is different to the overhead the Object has in memory. e.g. if you serialise an `Integer` it takes 81 bytes. However a String with 100 characters in it takes only 117 bytes. (As the string is UTF-8 encoded)

Comment: Using serialization here is *not* accurate. Because serialization does not include empty slots of the hashmap; at the same time it adds lots of overhead such as object type information. **Don't rely on serialization for data structure size information**. You are in fact measuring a very different data structure (a hashmap will be serialized as a sequential list of entries, and re-hashed on deserialization - so when serialized it is not a hash map anymore)!

Comment: the question text said **estimate** the usage.  It didn't say *give the exact answer down to the byte*.  This was an interview question, this was not "add a feature to the jdk to calculate the exact size of an item in memory".  so here was one way to **estimate** the memory taken up by an object.