# Can I store 50 mb of string type key value pair data in Java Hash Map

Tags: java, string, hashmap, size

I want to store around 5 million unique strings in Java hash map. Key and value will be the same string. String maximum length will be 15 characters (ASCII).Later I want to lookup whether a particular string exists in the hash map.

Do i need to worry about the memory size issue for the above scenario. I am guessing like it wont need more than 75 mb to 150 mb memory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure set maximum heap size `-Xmx` greater than 150MB....https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM160

Comment: Also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157363/how-to-calculate-hashmap-memory-usage-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Key and value will be the same string.

Using a `Map` when its keys and values will be the same is redundant.  You should use a `Set` instead, especially if you only plan to use `contains`.

Regarding your concern about space, let's assume that each `String` has a length of 15 characters.

Assuming you're using Java 9, Latin 1 characters only require a single `byte`, so 5 million unique `String`s will require at most `75_000_000` bytes or `75 MB`.

Java 8 and below back their `String`s with `char[]`, so you'd essentially require twice as much memory in that case.

Comment: Hi Jacob G., Is it okay to use a set? Do I need to worry about that 75 mb size or is it totally fine. I guess I am having java 8. I am new to java and dont know much about the effects with the versions.

Comment: It would be wise to use a `Set`, as it's backed by a `Map`, but its value is unused (less memory than duplicating your `String`).  `75 MB` should be perfectly fine, as long as you're able to allocate enough heap space (which I assume you can do).  For Java 8, you'll require at most `150 MB` (plus some overhead) for the `Set` alone.

Comment: @JacobG.You're right in saying that you should use a `Set` but not for the reason you said. If you set the same instance as key and value, the size isn't twice as much because only references are set and that size is independent of the length of the e.g. `String` behind it. You should use a `Set` because it's showing to readers of the code what you're doing, otherwise you might be confused why you set the key as value as well.

Comment: JLS: "Instances of class String represent sequences of Unicode code points." If your strings contain characters outside what Latin 1 can represent, they are going to occupy two bytes per character in Java 9.