# How much size a HashMap will consume?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have been recently asked a question in an interview like, if a HashMap with 100 key-value pairs is created how much memory it will consume..? Can anyone explain also how much each Entry in the map consumes .

Comment: Strictly speaking, this cannot be answered in general because it is an implementation detail.

Comment: In practice, there is this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157363/how-to-calculate-hashmap-memory-usage-in-java

Comment: don't accept the job offer. run. RUN.

Comment: The interview answer should make clear, that (simplified!) a hash map reserves internally a larger array than 100 entries, in order to find one or more entries by hash code modulo array size. This array is controlled by an initial capacity - _size_ - and a load factor (0.0 - 1.0).

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the platform e.g. JVM using compressed opts, object alignment in memory, collisions in hashing, etc. On top of that you would have to include the size of key and entry, which are separate objects. To get the actual memory usage of a data structure you should check the memory dump but even then [it's not straightforward](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/).

If you can possibly simplify the question to size, capacity and load factor of a standard `java.util.HashMap` then:

- By design the capacity is always a power of 2, so the size has to be at least 128.
- The default load factor is 0.75. To store 100 elements with a load factor of 0.75 we need a capacity 256 because 128 won't be enough (128 * 0.75 = 96 < 100).
- Because of above `HashMap` will store a `Node[] table` with a size of 256 to accommodate 100 elements.