# How to calculate the memory consumed by hash map?

Tags: android, memory, hashmap

How can i calculate the memory of hash map. The memory of hash map is what i want to get.

The size of hash map i can get through `hashmap.size();`

But i don't know how to get this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160485/3615605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, by using a couple of output streams from the java.io library:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
hashmap.put("vishal", 10); 
hashmap.put("sachin", 30); 
hashmap.put("vaibhav", 20);

try {
    System.out.println("HashMap Size: " + hashmap.size());
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream stream2 = new ObjectOutputStream(stream1);
    stream2.writeObject(hashmap);
    stream2.close();
    System.out.println("Memory Used: " + stream1.size());
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You could also try to use external tools/APIs like ClassMexer or the Instrumentation interface.