# Memory Aquired by Java String & HashMap memory size in java with UTF-8 string

Tags: java, memory, hashmap, jvm, garbage-collection

I have a hashmap in java which is type of <String,String>.
My requirement is i want to know how much memory it is taking in my system.
Please consider below details as well.

String Type is : UTF-8

MapType: HashMap<String, String>=new HashMap();

lenght of Map is: 7200000 (72 lacks key value pair)

Avg Length of key is : 75 (example: IUCC_SESSION_IUCC_SESSION_CALL_SUCC_-1102343625_2022-09-20T18:45:41.000000Z)

The length of the value is : 5 (example: VALUE)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157363/how-to-calculate-hashmap-memory-usage-in-java   this link may help you ..

Comment: There is no such thing as “String Type is UTF-8”. The Java implementation decides how strings are internally stored.