# Printing a dictionary into a file and checking file size to know the memory usage of that dictionary

Tags: java, groovy, heap-memory

I'm trying to figure out how much memory a dictionary uses, but I'm highly restricted in classes I can import and use for security reasons (using Jenkins, so I basically always get `Scripts not permitted to use new java.{library}`)

Anyhow, I was wondering if printing the dictionary into a file, and checking the file size afterwards would give a roughly accurate representation of how much heap space the dictionary uses.

Is this a viable approach?

Comment: Probably not. But this depends on the details of the contents of the dictionary, and how you write it to the file.

Comment: It also depends on what type the "dictionary" really is - I assume [Groovy `Map`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_maps), which is implemented as a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). This actually only stores references, so any contained Objects are stored elsewhere. Are you interested in the map itself (the references and the internal overhead) or the actual data refered from there?

Comment: See also this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157363/how-to-calculate-hashmap-memory-usage-in-java

Comment: Also see https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/ - even with a profiling tool analyzing a heapdump, the precise in-memory size may be different from the rteported one. If you need the data to be exact, you'll need a tool that runs in the same VM.